# How to reduce the resolution of a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, resize, resolution

I want to reduce the resolution of a video from 1024*768 to 800*600.
I found on the web ffmpeg, and the library swscale (I use  in C.

And I found some informations on the web, but nothing about how to reduce the resolution of a video nor about which functions to use

How can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/swscale-example_8c-source.html) or [this](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial08.html) example code. Use [sws_getContext](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__libsws.html#gaf360d1a9e0e60f906f74d7d44f9abfdd)() to set up a scaler, and [sws_scale](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__libsws.html#gae531c9754c9205d90ad6800015046d74)() to convert one frame or slice.